# Mock JMS MessageSource

Tags: java, spring, jms, mockito, spring-integration

I have a set of `MessageSource`s (in fact `JmsDestinationPollingSource`s) which are polled regularly. Under the hood this is an Oracle AQ database that persists queue items.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "queueSourceChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
public MessageSource queueSource() {
    return Jms
            .inboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
            .configureJmsTemplate(t -> t.deliveryPersistent(true)
                            .jmsMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter)
            ).destination(queueName).get();
}
```

However, now, I would like to make a `@SpringBootTest` without the Oracle persistence of course.

The way I did this now, was by mocking (Mockito) the above Bean:

```
@MockBean(name = "queueSource")
private MessageSource queueSource;
```

This way, the test class can be run, without having to worry that the MessageSource is polled.

However, as I mentioned, I have multiple MessageSource's and I'd like to disable this polling another way.

The way I'm doing this now is stupid:

```
@MockBean(name = "queueSource")
private MessageSource queueSource;

@MockBean(name = "queueSource2")
private MessageSource queueSource2;

@MockBean(name = "queueSource3")
private MessageSource queueSource3;

.. and so on
```

I tried to Mock all MessageSources, or all JmsDestinationPollingSource's but that seems hard (I read about PowerMockito but didn't try it out yet because I think it can be done differently).

I thought that it should also be possible to disable the Poller in the test scope. 
I suppose there are more solutions to my problem that I didn't think of.
All help is appreciated!

Comment: maybe `autoStartup=false` in the InboundChannelAdapter?

Comment: `autoStartup` might work, but then I need to start each bean manually... or not?

Answer (score 0):

Starting version 5.0 Spring Integration provides [Testing Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M5/reference/html/testing.html#test-context) with the Mocks on the matter as well.

There is a `@SpringIntegrationTest` with the property:

```
/**
 * Specify a simple matching patterns ("xxx*", "*xxx", "*xxx*" or "xxx*yyy") for
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint}
 * bean names to mark them as {@code autoStartup = false}
 * during context initialization.
 * @return the endpoints name patterns to stop during context initialization
 * @see IntegrationEndpointsInitializer
 * @see org.springframework.util.PatternMatchUtils
 */
String[] noAutoStartup() default {};
```

That is how it can be useful for your use-case.

Another option can be done with the `@Profile` when you don't even create beans if profile is `test` for example.

Otherwise you don't have choice unless stop all the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` beans by this type or their names in the beginning of the test.

Comment: Thank you Artem Bilan, I will give this annotation a try soon.
The @Profile is not really an option because I need those sources on other parts in my configuration.